# MySQL TIME_TO_SEC with fractional seconds

Tags: mysql

I currently have fields that use a `time(6)` type. Values would be something like `00:01:03.125000`. When I use

`SELECT TIME_TO_SEC("00:01:03.125000")`

I want it to give me `63.125` or `63.125000`, but instead it rounds it to `63`.

Is there a MySQL function that will provide me with the time value in fractional seconds? If not, what workaround should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `MICROSECOND` to the seconds

```
TIME_TO_SEC("00:01:03.125000") + MICROSECOND("00:01:03.125") / 1000000
```

Result: `63.125`

or

use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function with `MICROSECOND`

```
 TIMESTAMPDIFF( MICROSECOND, CURDATE(), ADDTIME(CURDATE(), "00:01:03.125000") ) / 1000000
```

Result: `63.125`